# Store user credentials to avoid re-typing

Tags: cordova, authentication, encryption, oauth-2.0, local-storage

I am working on a web app (Angular2) which authenticate with a BackEnd using OAuth2. The credentials (i.e. username/password) are sent to the backend in plain text over HTTPS. The backend replies with Token and RefreshToken. 
Everything seems to work fine, except that being a single page app with token expiry time of 30 minutes, the user is automatically logged out after a period of inactivity and they need to type the credentials again.

The only exception is in a web browser where you can store them (Chrome/Firefox) so you don't need to type them again.

On mobile (through cordova), typing a difficult password might not be ideal, so I am exploring different approaches, mostly looking at other questions on SO.

Recap:

1. storing the credentials using localStorage is not safe. If the phone is stolen, it's easy enough to sniff the credentials
2. storing the credentials using iOS keychain seems better but not unbreakable. is there an alternative on Android?
3. setting the Refresh Token expiry time to one month instead of few minutes, might be an alternative so that the user is not logged out for a month. I believe you don't need to store the Refresh Token anywhere but leave in the app memory. This seems a good approach, but if anyone can sniff the RefreshToken then they have access to BE requests forever.
4. Encrypt the credentials on the server and send them back to the client to be securely stored on the device. Again I don't see too much benefit since this means that the BE accepts logins with clear credentials or encrypted credentials, but if you steal the encrypted ones you can use them anyway.

Outcome:
I am confused and I don't understand what's the best approach. How Google/Facebook/Twitter/etc. solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a very few options available to achieve this but yes, it is possible.

- **Use SessionStorage** - Use sessionStorage instead of localStorage. the keys/values stored in sessionStorage will be cleared on the next app launch. This may not help securing your app completely but surely can minimize the risk.
- **encrypt them locally** - use [cordova-plugin-secure-storage](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage) to encrypt the user input using a random 256-bit AES key. This plugin will handle encrypting and decrypting
- **BONUS! Encrypt your app itself** - To add a extra layer of security, use [cordova-plugin-crypt-file](https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file) to encrypt your source file themselves and prevent anyone from view your code and figure out what's going on.

Comment: the first one is not an option since I want to "save" the credentials so that the user doesn't need to type the password every time the app launches.

Comment: Yeah agree. just thought it won't hurt mentioning if this can provide a little bit of help. :)

Comment: I don't get the last one. Where is the encryption key stored?